# CSS scroll bar styling conundrum

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a container with the CSS property `overflow: auto`.
I know how to give styles to the scroll bar, but I don't understand how I can:

1) move scroll bar from right border of container at least 5 pixels left.

2) scrollbar-thumb part should be than scrollbar-track part.

Example code in "SCSS":

```
#msg-console {
    height: 48rem;
    width: 100%;
    background: #04aaf8;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 1rem;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        border-radius: 1rem;
        background: rgba(74, 49, 106, 0.9);
        width: 0.5rem;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 1rem;
        background: #fff;
        width: 0.3rem;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me?
I looking for CSS solutions only.

Comment: can share your html code ?

Comment: The html code looks like:<div id="wrapper"><div id="msg-console"></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

So for me, I found simple and working solution. I just added additional internal div.
styles:

```
#msg-console {
    height: 48rem;
    width: 100%;
    background: #04aaf8;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .msg-container{
                height: 48rem;
                overflow-y: auto;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                width: 99%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0 0.5rem;

                 &::-webkit-scrollbar {
                     width: 1rem;
                }

                 &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                     border-radius: 1rem;
                     background: rgba(74, 49, 106, 0.9);
                     width: 0.5rem;
                 }

                &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                    border-radius: 1rem;
                    background: #fff;
                    width: 0.3rem;
                }
   }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="msg-console>
     <div class="msg-container"><div>
</div>
```